# How to ignore output ports with port maps

Tags: port, vhdl

Well often in VHDL I notice that a certain component has multiple output ports. Ie in one of our examples we were given the following component:

```
COMPONENT eight_bitadder
  PORT ( a, b: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
        f: in std_logic; 
        C: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
        o, z: out std_logic);
END COMPONENT;
```

Where z determines if the result is 0, and o triggers on overflow.

Now in my case I wish to use this adder, however the actual result is not of importance, rather I only wish to check if the result is "0". I could of course add a dummy signal and store the port to this signal, however that seems needlessly complicated, and might add extra components during synthesis?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you instantiate the component you can leave the output ports that you don't care about open.  The only signal you care about below is "overflow".

EDIT: Note that the synthesis tools will optimize away any outputs that are not being used.

```
EIGHT_BITADDER_INST : eight_bitadder
  port map (
    a => a,
    b => b, 
    f => f, 
    c => open, 
    o => overflow,
    z => open
    );
```

Comment: So open is a special keyword - can this also be used with the syntax where you don't explicitly name the ports, and use the order? (just asking for verification/clarity)?

Comment: Yes, "open" is reserved in VHDL.  Honestly I have never tried that, give it a shot and let me know how it goes.  I always explicitly declare the port mapping.

Comment: well tested it and yes, I could compile & synthesize it, even with the non explicit naming. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You also could choose to not tie an output to anything like so:

```
EIGHT_BITADDER_INST : eight_bitadder
    port map (
    a => a,
    b => b, 
    f => f, 
    o => overflow
);
```

Notice that I simply did not include outputs c and z in the port map.  Some may debate on the clarity of this (since it may not be clear that outputs c and z exists), but it also reduces the code to only what is necessary.

Comment: Note that it might be necessary to also remove the lines from your component declaration or assign default values to the ports you're removing. If you don't then you might run into errors when trying to compile.

Comment: @TW80000 I can confirm this. This is why this answer is not the best.